# How to get rectangular multiple selection behavior in Comtl32.dll ListView

Tags: winapi, comctl32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListView multiple selection behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383918/listview-multiple-selection-behavior)

The `ListView` in `Comtl32.dll` v6.0 does multiple selection (when using Shift key) as follows (x means selected)

```
00xxxx
xxxxxx
xxxx00
```

Earlier versions of ListView do it as follows :

```
00xx00
00xx00
00xx00
```

Is there any way to have it do the first way (the comctl32 v6.0 way)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to make a rectangular selection, rather than a sequential selection?